# How can I find the MySQL command that phpMyAdmin runs when I do a quick database export?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My current workflow for migrating MySQL databases between servers is to log into phpMyAdmin, choose the database, select the Quick method, and export the database as a .sql file. Then I switch database servers, create a database of the same name on the new server, and use phpMyAdmin to import the .sql file. I'd like to know the exact command that phpMyAdmin runs to export the database.

Both MySQL instances were recently migrated from 5.5 to 5.7 with minimal problems. These databases are for Drupal 8 web sites. I've tried using mysqldump with default settings, but it must not include all the necessary data, since the site doesn't work properly if I import a .sql file created with mysqldump instead of through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: It's probably using its own code to create the file, not running an external command.

Comment: Try comparing the files created with PhpMyAdmin and mysqldump, to see what's missing in the latter.